# Express not sending cross domain cookies

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, graphql, cross-domain

#### Introduction

I have a problem with sending cross domain session cookie and after searching I got even more confused.
Originally I had a client (Next app) on `foo.vercel.com` and the api (Express) on `bar.heroku.com`.
Sending and saving cookies was working correctly on localhost, but after deployment I got a problem with the `sameSite` set to `lex` by default. So I changed it to `none`. But I found that the `sameSite none` requires `secure` flag on the cookie set, so I also changed that.

#### The problem

After setting `secure` to `true` the cookie is no longer being sent.

> If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, ***the cookie will not be set***.

Both my server and client are hosted on HTTPS. I checked the logs on the heroku and the request protocol is HTTPS... however when I console.log a `request.protocol` from a GraphQL resolver the protocol is HTTP:
[image: Different protocols]

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342167/11348608)

> There's no such thing as cross domain cookies. You could share a cookie between foo.example.com and bar.example.com but never between example.com and example2.com

I moved the client to `baz.heroku.com` but the problem remains.

In order to check if everything still works I disabled the ***Cookies without SameSite must be secure*** in `chrome://flags` and it works correctly.

#### Questions

1. Is it even possible to set cookie cross domain?
2. Why does the POST method have different protocol than request I get in express server.
   (I get the request from express and pass it through context to GraphQL resolvers)
3. And of course how can I send cookie to the client on different domain.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Heroku's proxy. I had to add the following to the express server:

```
 app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

Comment: This only works for desktop for me. Not mobile